# Google Developer Console does not give password when creating Service Account

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

Overall goal is trying to access (my own) Google Sheets with a server-side PHP application (not for sheets owned by individual app visitors).  For this I'm hoping to use https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client, which mentions that it doesn't handle the OAuth2 stuff, for which I can use https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.

So in trying to follow https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts , it says (step 5):

> The Console shows your private key's password only at this initial moment of service account creation--the password will not be shown again

However when I do those steps, it sends me a .json (with private_key_id, private_key, client_email, client_id, type), but at no point does it show me any kind of password.  I have tried this with both Firefox and Chromium, tried deleting my old Service Account, making a new Service Account.  Is there something else I need to enable on my Developers Console? or something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a service account on the Google Api Console, usually, the file randomname.p12 will get downloaded automatically, and the password for this file will be `notasecret` but, if you are authenticating using the service account i beleive you dont need the password, even tho i am using it, see here [check out bram answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472059/zend-gdata-and-google-spreadsheet-not-connecting/30499886?noredirect=1#comment49139756_30499886) he is authenticating using a service account, which might be what you are looking for